# Let be a function defined by $F(x,y)=(x^3-\alpha xy^2, \alpha x^2y-y^3)$. How can I define $\alpha$ such as $F$ is a conformal map?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, conformal-geometry

Let be a function defined by $F(x,y)=(x^3-\alpha xy^2, \alpha x^2y-y^3)$. How can I define $\alpha$ such as $F$ is a conformal map?

Also, let $F$ be a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\alpha$ be a constant over $\mathbb{R}$.

I understand the definition of a conformal map, but I can't figure how to tell if a function is conformal or not.

I'm leaving a big thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: a map is conformal when its jacobian is a scalar times a rotation matrix

Comment: $F(x, y)$ can at best be conformal on $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$; see my answer below.

Comment: I added the "complex-analysis" tag to your post.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a slight error in the problem statement:  we only have a solution on $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$, so technically we should define $F:\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{ 0 \} \to \Bbb R^2$, as is made more clear below:

The mapping

$F(x, y) = (x^3 - \alpha x y^2, \alpha x^2 y - y^3) = (u(x, y), v(x, y)) \tag 1$

is conformal if and only if the function

$f(z) = f(x, y) = u(x, y) + i v(x, y) \tag 2$

is holomorphic and $f'(z) \ne 0$ (see [this wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map)), as will be case if $z = x + iy \ne 0$ and $u(x, y)$ and $v(x, y)$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemmann equations

$u_x = v_y, \tag 3$

$u_y =  -v_x; \tag 4$

applying (3) to $u(x, y)$ and $v(x, y)$ as defined in (1) yields

$3x^2 - \alpha y^2 = \alpha x^2 - 3y^2; \tag 5$

from (5) we conclude that

$\alpha = 3; \tag 6$

indeed, (5) may be written

$3(x^2 + y^2) = \alpha (x^2 + y^2), \tag 7$

from which (6) immediately follows for any $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$.  We then see that

$f(z) = (x^3 - 3 x y^2) + i(3x^2 y - y^3) = (x + iy)^3 = z^3, \tag 8$

a manifestly holomorphic function.

The reader may easily check that (4) holds with this pair $u(x, y)$, $v(x, y)$ as well.  We see this is the only possible choice of $\alpha$; with $\alpha = 3$, the function $F(x, y)$ is therefore conformal except at $z = x + iy = 0$, and there is no alternative to the loss of conformality at $z = 0$.

Therefore, in any event,

$\alpha = 3. \tag 9$